# How to verify if toast message is displayed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

The scenario here is I'm saving data and after a successful save a toast message is displayed but if I lets say save the toast message as a WebElement and verify .isDisplayed() won't work because I think it would be displayed as element would be present in DOM anyways so any other way to assert a data save in grid using toast message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for validation the toast is displayed I use in my project:

```java
Assert.assertTrue(validateToastMessageAppearance("invalid Entitlement"));
```

Where `validateToastMessageAppearance` method defined as

```java
public boolean validateToastMessageAppearance(String message){
    return waitForElementToBeVisible(String.format(toastMessage,message));
}
```

The method `waitForElementToBeVisible` is defined as:

```java
public boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(By.xpath(xpath)) {
    try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(xpath));
    return true;
    }catch (Throwable t){
        return false;
    }
}
```

While `toastMessage` is defined as

```java
public String toastMessage = toast + textElement;
```

Where

```java
public String toast =  "//div[contains(@class,'ToastContent')]";
```

and

```java
public String textElement = "//*[contains(text(),'%s')]";
```

Comment: As written validateToastMessageAppearance() will always return true.  Looks like your intent was to write it as:

`public boolean validateToastMessageAppearance(String message) {`
`return waitForElementToBeVisible(String.format(toastMessage,message));`
` }`

Comment: Thanks @dsharp! Looks like you are right! I no more work on that project so I can't see what is the actual code there but I will correct the answer here